# Unable to repair packages in ubuntu

Tags: dpkg, synaptic

I'm unable to repair programs through either use of the terminal or synaptic package manager. I keep getting this message.

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+15.04.20150415.1-0ubuntu2

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems that parts of KDE remained after I uninstalled kubuntu desktop. This is preventing me from installing or uninstalling programs.
help appreciated!

Comment: Please try to format in block code (empty line and 4 spaces in the beginning) because it is quite difficult to read it like that.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not both packages (`kde-config-telepathy-accounts` and `account-plugin-google`) installed at the same time, because the file `/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service` is included in both packages.

The package `kde-config-telepathy-accounts` is installed through a PPA, which you added to your system. The [officially package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/kde-config-telepathy-accounts) package does not have this problem.

Therefore, purge the PPA or remove the package `kde-config-telepathy-accounts` via

```
sudo apt-get remove kde-config-telepathy-accounts
```

**OR**

remove the package `account-plugin-google` via

```
sudo apt-get remove account-plugin-google
```

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)